# CPU core overload? Audio randomly glitch for 1-2 seconds

Tags: audio, memory, cpu

I don't know why I have random glitches while listening to audio lately, it never happened before. My computer is rather good, and memory is enough: 6GB ram / 4 cpu.

In order to find the problem, I opened the System Process monitor meanwhile until I got the glitch. I usually have about 15 tabs in Chrome, but it is normal. It seems to that it's related to the CPU #1 usage. Do you know what could be the problem ?

Screenshot:

[image]

[Here is a CPU-Z full-report of my PC](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30076751/KAMCHATKA-PC.html)

edit: on-board audio card. Windows 7 64-bit Ultimate. Full report in the link above.

Comment: please list the motherboard model number or your sound card model number if its an adapter, and what OS

Comment: Thanks chipperyman573 for including the screenshot in the post. I hadn't got enought points to do it.

Comment: looks like you have DPC issues: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140263